# How flat file item reader in spring batch works

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a csv file with 2Gb size and i’m using spring batch to read the csv file using flatfile item reader after that we are processing and writing data to kafka. We are using chunk size as 200 in reader part.The issue is we are getting **Out of memory Error** as per my knowledge after processing 200 chunk records it should free the memory, but why I’m getting out of memory issue

We tried to debug but didn’t find out the issue

Comment: try to increase  the java heap space

Comment: you can use streaming for reading a file, it will not load all the file lines at once, it may work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The `FlatFileItemReader` does not load the entire file in memory, it streams data from it chunk by chunk.

Items should be garbage collected after each processed chunk. If you have an Out of memory Error, this means that there is something holding a reference to them items after chunk processing, or you did not allocate enough memory for your app to be able to load a single chunk in memory (in which case, you should either increase the memory or decrease the chunk size).